# Can't update system due to "Error in validating some packages."

Tags: updates

I have a little problem updating my ubuntu. I have not update it for a while and I tried today. The problem is that I tried 3 time, and there is the same problem. 
The problem says something like this: "Error in validating some packages. Could not authenticate some packages. This may be due to temporary network problems. You can try later. Beneath you have a list of the packages that could not authenticate."

And there are a lot of packages.

Answer (score 0):

For the other problems, I would recommend running all of the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: ok, I'm a beginner in using ubuntu and I don't know how to use these codes... I ask a lot before doing something :P

Comment: Open terminal => Ctrl + Alt + T
& execute codes :

1rst : `sudo apt-get clean`
2 : `cd /var/lib/apt`
.......